# C# MVC4 Binding Array As Nested Type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model that looks like this

```
 public class ViewModel
 {
    public Dictionary<int, int[]> SelectedRoomIds 
 }
```

On my page I have something like this

```
@foreach(var floor in floors)
{
        @Html.Hidden("SelectedRoomIds.Index", floor)
        @Html.Hidden("SelectedRoomIds[" + floor + "].Key", floor)
        @Html.ListBox("SelectedRoomIds[" + floor + "].Value", Model.FloorSelectList)
}
```

This works (binds) great if at least one item is selected in **any** of the list boxes, but it throws an exception that I can't seem to trap somewhere if nothing is selected. If nothing is selected I would expect either the key exists with a null int array or the entire dictionary be null. Neither is the case. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: sorry i was using mvc 5, i guess the issue has been fixed in 5, i have reproduced an issue in mvc 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVC 4 default model binder seems to throw a invalid cast exception when a value is not posted for a specific key, this problem exist for any array type in the generic dictionary value, where no value is posted on the form, whether it be a string[] or object[].

I haven't had time to dig into the MVC 4 source code yet, the issue is **fixed in MVC 5**, if you can upgrade do so, if not you can **create your own model binder** to deal with the issue, if you don't have time to do that you can try the below and change your int array to be a array of nullable ints:

```
public Dictionary<int, int?[]> SelectedRoomIds { get; set; }
```

and add a empty value placeholder in your view before your select list you it will work, only side effect is you will always have a null item in your array:

```
@Html.Hidden("SelectedRoomIds.Index", floor)
@Html.Hidden("SelectedRoomIds[" + floor + "].Key", floor)
@Html.Hidden("SelectedRoomIds[" + floor + "].Value", "")
@Html.ListBox("SelectedRoomIds[" + floor + "].Value", Model.FloorSelectList)
```

to make the dictionary easier to consume you can create a backing field and add a getter to remove all null values from the dictionary values.

Comment: This is a possible solution and does work so I will mark it as the answer. I opted to go with a custom model binder I found through other questions and a few modifications made it suit my needs. 

https://github.com/loune/MVCStuff/blob/master/Extensions/DefaultDictionaryBinder.cs